# Unable to list all vertices present in Janusgraph with ".toList()" using Gremlinpython

Tags: python, cassandra, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I have tried testing what is in a graph that I created to see whether nodes were indeed created.

The code to create a small graph for testing:

```
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))

# in a loop add nodes and properties to get a small graph for testing
t = g.addV('testnode').property('val',1)
    for i in range(2,11):
    t = g.addV('testnode').property('val', i)
    t.iterate()

# proceed to create edge (as_ and from_ contain an underscore because as & from are python's reserved words)
g.V().has("val", 2).as_("a").V().has("val", 4).as_("b").addE("link").property("someproperty", "abc").from_("a").to("b").iterate()

list1 = []
list1 = g.V().has("val", 2).toList()
print(len(list1))
```

to which I would expect to have the value "1" returned in the terminal, which happened correctly while testing previously (and now fails).
However, this returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_addingVEs.py", line 47, in <module>
    list1 = g.V().has("val_i", 2).toList()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 52, in toList
    return list(iter(self))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 43, in __next__
    self.traversal_strategies.apply_strategies(self)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py", line 346, in apply_strategies
    traversal_strategy.apply(traversal)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/remote_connection.py", line 143, in apply
    remote_traversal = self.remote_connection.submit(traversal.bytecode)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py", line 54, in submit
    results = result_set.all().result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 405, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/resultset.py", line 81, in cb
    f.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 77, in _receive
    self._protocol.data_received(data, self._results)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py", line 98, in data_received
    "{0}: {1}".format(status_code, message["status"]["message"]))
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 598: 
    A timeout occurred during traversal evaluation of [RequestMessage
    {, requestId=d56cce63-77f3-4c1f-9c14-3f5f33d4a67b, op='bytecode', processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[[], [V(), has(val, 2)]], aliases={g=g}}}]
     - consider increasing the limit given to scriptEvaluationTimeout
```

The .toList() function did work previously, but not anymore. 
Is there anything wrong in my code, or should I look elsewhere for a possible cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error is indicating the problem:

```
A timeout occurred during traversal evaluation of [RequestMessage
    {, requestId=d56cce63-77f3-4c1f-9c14-3f5f33d4a67b, op='bytecode', processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[[], [V(), has(val, 2)]], aliases={g=g}}}]
     - consider increasing the limit given to scriptEvaluationTimeout
```

Of course, assuming the default `scriptEvaluationTimeout` of 30 seconds, it should not take that long to return a result of the query you are executing unless you have a significant amount of vertices and you do not have an index on "val". So given that your graph is really small, I don't see why such an execution would take so long.

I don't know what you're environment is like that you're testing on, but if you're running all of JanusGraph/Cassandra on a highly underpowered machine I guess something highly resource starved could take a long time to execute. I think that I would try to increase the `scriptEvaluationTimeout` as suggested in the error to see just how high you have to increase it to get the result back. If you don't have indices on `val` you probably should add those anyway (though I don't think that's your problem unless that vertex count is bigger than your code is indicating).

Comment: Thank you Stephen for your answer! I am using a relatively new, well equipped machine, so I think there can be no issue regarding this. I will regardless try to increase the time as you suggest (although I think the issue is elsewhere). Thanks again for your elaborate answer!